# iOS posting to Instagram not working

Tags: ios, ios6, uidocumentinteraction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [UIDocumentInteractionController no longer works in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631466/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-no-longer-works-in-ios6)

I can't open Instagram from my app. Here's the code I'm using:

```
NSString  *imageToUpload = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents/mapapic-instagram.igo"];
NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);
[imageData writeToFile:imageToUpload atomically:YES];

_documentInteractionController 
    = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:imageToUpload]];
_documentInteractionController.delegate = self;
_documentInteractionController.UTI = @"com.instagram.exclusivegram";
NSString *defaultInstagramText = @"Hello";

_documentInteractionController.annotation = @{ @"InstagramCaption" : defaultInstagramText };
BOOL success = [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero 
                                                                  inView:self.view.window
                                                                animated:YES];
```

The last call returns YES. Yet nothing happens, and Instagram is not opened. The `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` methods are not called. I have the Instagram app installed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Found the solution! See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631466/uidocumentinteractioncontroller-no-longer-works-in-ios6.

Comment: Post your find as an answer and then accept it

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I needed to change to make it work (changing `self.view.window` to `self.view` in the call below).

```
BOOL success = [_documentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero 
                                                                  inView:self.view.window
                                                                animated:YES];
```

Apparently the behavior of `UIDocumentInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated` was changed in iOS 6, which broke my code, which used to work before. I'll later test this change in iOS 5 to see if it still works there.