# Still no UIDocumentInteractionController in iOS 6

Tags: ios, ios6, uidocumentinteraction

I have followed the suggestions in the existing questions on this topic ([UIDocumentInteractionController doesn't work since iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15881176) and [UIDocumentInteractionController no longer works in iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631466)), but I'm still having trouble with UIDocumentInteractionController under iOS 6.

My app is a single UIView (`myview`) that implements `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate`, there is no view controller. In `touchesBegan`, there is the following code:

```
UIDocumentInteractionController *dic;
dic = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
dic.delegate =self;
[dic retain];

if([dic presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:myview animated:NO])
    result=1;
```

This works fine on iOS 5, a list with compatible apps is presented, the apps start when selected and load the file specified in `fileURL`. On iOS 6, nothing happens, but `result` still indicates success. It is as if the options menu was hidden.

Could it be because I'm using iOS SDK 4.3?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it was because I was using iOS SDK 4.3. After switching to 6.1, it works fine.

(If you wonder why I use an old SDK in the first place: My computer is too old, it can't be updated beyond OS X 10.6.8 while the latest Xcode / iOS SDK requires 10.7.)